Pagination incorrect due to custom exposed filter
I have created a custom exposed filter, which does work. The results are filtered correctly. But the full pager does not show the correct number of pages. Even if I do have only one page of results, there are thousands of pages in the pagination. Is there any option to pass the correct number of results to the pagination?
See my current custom exposed filter class:

declare(strict_types=1);

namespace Drupal\dhb_news\Plugin\views\filter;

use Drupal\Core\Database\Connection;
use Drupal\Core\Session\AccountProxyInterface;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\RequestStack;

/**
 * @ingroup views_filter_handlers
 *
 * @ViewsFilter("news_date_range_filter")
 */
class NewsDateRangeFilter extends DateRangeFilter {

  public function __construct(array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, Connection $connection, RequestStack $requestStack, AccountProxyInterface $currentUser) {
    parent::__construct($configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition, $connection, $requestStack, $currentUser);
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public static function create(ContainerInterface $container, array $configuration, $plugin_id, $plugin_definition) {
    return new static(
      $configuration,
      $plugin_id,
      $plugin_definition,
      $container->get('database'),
      $container->get('request_stack'),
      $container->get('current_user')
    );
  }

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function query() {
    if ($this->isDateRangeSelected()) {
      /** @var \Drupal\views\Plugin\views\query\Sql $query */
      $query = $this->query;
      $table = array_key_first($query->tables);

      $queryParams = $this->prepareQueryParams();
      $query->addWhere($this->options['group'], $table . '.created', $queryParams->from->getTimestamp(), '>=');
      $query->addWhere($this->options['group'], $table . '.created', $queryParams->to->getTimestamp(), '<=');
    }

    // Preserve other filters defined in the Views UI.
    $this->ensureMyTable();
  }

}



Where's the date range filter class from? Does it work correctly? (The pagination is created by a count query and if all is well, that should be filtered in exactly the same way as the main query).

I found a solution. There is this Pager-ID field in the views pager settings. After trying a couple things, I've tried to set a different numeric ID there, too. Afterwards this pager and other pagers worked correctly. The description of this field also suggests, that it can help, if there are "problems". So there might be some side effects, which can be worked around by this field setting. Maybe this information helps others also. Lost a couple of hours with this.
See attached screenshot:

